# Facebook signed_request Invalid

Tags: php, facebook

So I've been fiddling about with creating a Facebook Page App and am running into an obstacle.

The API Documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) indicates that it is a json encoded base64 encoded string, but I've found that more often then not it doesn't decode (PHP) properly.

Example String

[signed_request] => ccskn7MGtWvG9XXAU5F8nE61aFy-PP-2Jmvz35iwtOo.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM4NjEyNTk5NCwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjM5ODYxMDQ0MDIxNDI2NiIsImxpa2VkIjpmYWxzZSwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJ1cyIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuX1VTIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0

I did find this other question ([Invalid base64 in Facebook signed_request documentation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890608/invalid-base64-in-facebook-signed-request-documentation-example)), but after trying to add padding, still not gibberish results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you replaced the characters `-` and `_` by `+` and `/` respectively before trying to base64 decode it …?

Comment: I have, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: The example signed request that you posted decodes perfectly fine.

Comment: Whaa? I get `q$kuS|Nh\?bf=N쉅ɥѡ!5M!؈Օ}Ја쉥؈际͔Օ͕Ȉ쉍չ̈艕}UL쉵` when I used `base64_decode()` - can you please share code?

Comment: Have you maybe forgotten to split the whole thing at the first dot, and only decode the second part?

Comment: That did the trick. Where was that documented? I didn't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the `signed_request`, first it must be split at the first dot `.` character, and then in the second part you have to replace the characters `-` and `_` by `+` and `/` respectively – and after that base64-decode it.

As for your question, where this is documented – in the document that is linked right on top of the document that you mentioned, here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/#parsingsr